# Sort values of matrix in python

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, matrix

What I have so far is:

```
dict={'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[2,5,4], 'C':[2,1,8]}
N=len(keys)
m=numpy.zeros(N,N)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
         m[i-1,j-1]=covariance(values[i-1],values[j-1])
         m[j-1,i-1]=covariance(values[j-1],values[i-1])
m=numpy.triu(m)
```

which gives me:

```
1   0.639  0.07
0     1    0.51
0     0      1
```

I dont have the column names or the row names yet. I would like something like this:

```
       A     B      C
A      1   0.639  0.07
B      0     1    0.51
C      0     0      1
```

Given this matrix, I would like to sort it in descending order by the value of the matrix so the output I would like is:

```
A & A: 1
B & B: 1
C & C: 1
A & B: 0.639
B & C: 0.51
A & C: 0.07
B & A: 0 #etc
```

From the output would like to save it into a csv file where the first column are the names and the second column are the corresponding scores

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to show what you have done before you ask a question. If you have no idea where to begin, here is a hint: read the data into a dictionary with the 'A & A' etc as the keys and then sort the dictioanry with the `sorted()` function using the `key` parameter.

Comment: edited what i have so far

Answer (score 2):

Call `np.sort` with the `axis` keyword argument set to `None`, then reverse it with slicing:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0.639, 0.07], [0, 1, 0.51], [0, 0, 1]])
>>> a
array([[ 1.   ,  0.639,  0.07 ],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.51 ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
>>> np.sort(a, axis=None)[::-1]
array([ 1.   ,  1.   ,  1.   ,  0.639,  0.51 ,  0.07 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ])
```

If you want to know where each value is coming from, then first use `np.argsort`, then unravel the flattened indices:

```
>>> idx = np.argsort(a, axis=None)[::-1]
>>> rows, cols = np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
>>> a_sorted = a[rows, cols]
>>> for r, c, v in zip(rows, cols, a_sorted):
...     print 'ABC'[r], '&', 'ABC'[c], ':', v
... 
C & C : 1.0
B & B : 1.0
A & A : 1.0
A & B : 0.639
B & C : 0.51
A & C : 0.07
C & B : 0.0
C & A : 0.0
B & A : 0.0
```

Comment: awesome. how would i go about pulling out the fact that 0.51 corresponds to "B&C"?

Comment: He wants the output he provided. :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a numpy array, like this:

```
matrix = numpy.array( [ [ 1, 0.639, 0.07 ],
                        [ 0, 1,     0.51 ],
                        [ 0, 0,     1 ]  ] )
```

you can do like this:

```
indices = ["A", "B", "C", ]                     

values = []

for r,row in enumerate( matrix ):
    for c, cell in enumerate( row ):
        values.append( ("{} & {}".format( indices[r], indices[c] ), cell ) )

values.sort( key=lambda it: (-it[1], it[0]) )

for k,v in values:
    print "{}: {}".format(k,v)
```

OUTPUT:

```
A & A: 1.0
B & B: 1.0
C & C: 1.0
A & B: 0.639
B & C: 0.51
A & C: 0.07
B & A: 0.0
C & A: 0.0
C & B: 0.0
```

Comment: Receiving an error: for k,v in values:
ValueError:too many values to unpack

Comment: how would i go about taking the output and saving it into a csv file

Comment: @user3334418 [csv module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [the code](http://pastebin.com/fHkzHEX9).